# Filesaver.js: how to write a blob containing binary data?

Tags: javascript, save, blob, filesaver.js

I want to use **[fileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)** to click a button and save a **binary blob** (type: "application/octet-stream").
But i don´t know how to save the blob the way i need it to be.

The final file (example.mod) needs to have the following sequence:

- `8`  (the number of bytes for the next peace of information, integer number)
- `<POINTS>` (a tag name with 8 characters)
- `3` (the number of points)
- `[A,10.5,10,10]` (a point: an array with a letter and 3 floating numbers)
- `[B,20,10,0.7]` (a point: an array with a letter and 3 floating numbers)
- `[C,10,20.3,10]` (a point: an array with a letter and 3 floating numbers)
- `9` (the number of bytes for the next peace of information, integer number)
- `</POINTS>` (a tag name with 9 characters)

I´ve found some examples saving "text/plain" or "image/png", but nothing that I could figure out how to apply in my case.

I've made this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/sergioprof/pen/VwmYpKM) showing what I´m trying to do, but the resulting file is not what expected!
it returns a file like that (all the information is visible as if was a text file):

```
8<POINTS>3A,10.5,10,10B,20,10,0.7C,10,20.3,109</POINTS>
```

...but what I would like to get is the file writen in Bytes, something like this (when looked at in a text-editor):

[image]

...or when read it as an ArrayBuffer I should get something like this result:

```
Int8Array(119)[
    0: 0
    1: 0
    2: 0
    3: 8
    4: 60
    5: 80
    6: 79
    7: 73
    8: 78
    9: 84
    10: 83
    11: 62
    12: 3
    13: 0
    14: 0
    15: 0
    16: 2
    17: 0
    18: 0
    19: 0
    20: 1
    21: 65
    22: 0
    23: 0
    24: 0
    25: 0
    26: 0
    27: 0
    28: 37
    29: 64
    30: 0
    31: 0
    32: 0
    33: 0
    34: 0
    35: 0
    36: 36
    37: 64
    38: 0
    39: 0
    40: 0
    41: 0
    42: 0
    43: 0
    44: 36
    45: 64
    46: 2
    47: 0
    48: 0
    49: 0
    50: 1
    51: 66
    52: 0
    53: 0
    54: 0
    55: 0
    56: 0
    57: 0
    ​​58: 52
    ​​59: 64
    ​​60: 0
    ​​61: 0
    ​​62: 0
    ​​63: 0
    ​​64: 0
    65: 0
    66: 36
    ​​67: 64
    ​​68: 102
    ​​69: 102
    ​​70: 102
    ​​71: 102
    72: 102
    ​​73: 102
    ​​74: -26
    ​​75: 63
    76: 2
    77: 0
    ​​78: 0
    79: 0
    ​​80: 1
    ​​81: 67
    ​​82: 0
    ​​83: 0
    ​​84: 0
    ​​85: 0
    ​​86: 0
    87: 0
    ​​88: 36
    ​​89: 64
    ​​90: -51
    ​​91: -52
    ​​92: -52
    ​​93: -52
    ​​94: -52
    ​​95: 76
    96: 52
    ​​97: 64
    98: 0
    ​​99: 0
    100: 0
    ​​101: 0
    ​​102: 0
    ​​103: 0
    ​​104: 36
    105: 64
    ​​106: 0
    107: 0
    108: 0
    ​​109: 9
    ​​110: 60
    ​​111: 47
    ​​112: 80
    ​​113: 79
    ​​114: 73
    ​​115: 78
    ​​116: 84
    ​​117: 83
    ​​118: 62
]
```

PS: If you know how to get those results without using filesaver.js, that would work for me as well.

**Any help will be most appreciated!**

**Thank you.**

Comment: I am trying to prepare the data with Arraybuffer e typed arrays before creating the blob, but with no success so far. Really lost here! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:**

After digging for a while found in different questions the bits and peaces i needed to put together a solution (not sure if is the best practice, but is working!)

First I had to treat every kind of input (string, number(positive integer), number(signed floating real) in differnet ways to match the format I need in the file.

[*1:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers/11058858#11058858) from here got the StingToArrayBuffer solution

```
//string to ArrayBuffer
function str2ab(str) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length); // 2 bytes for each char
  var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (var i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  var result = new Uint8Array(bufView.buffer);
  return result;
}
```

[*2:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55583037/convert-number-to-arraybuffer) From that answer got the numberToArrayBuffer solution, modified to my needs!

```
//.............number to ArratBuffer //*2
//integer To ArrayBuffer - 4 bits
function int2ArrBuf(value) {
  const view = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(4))
  for (var index = 3; index >= 0; --index) {
    view.setUint8(index, value % 256)
    value = value >> 8;
  }
  var int = new Uint8Array(view.buffer);
  return int
}

//Reverse order
function Xint2ArrBuf(value) {
  const view = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(4))
  for (var index = 0; index <= 3; ++index) {
    view.setUint8(index, value % 256)
    value = value >> 8;
  }
  var int = new Uint8Array(view.buffer);
  return int
}
//......................

//one bit long integer
function strsize(value) {
  const view = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(1))
  
    view.setUint8(0, value % 256)
    value = value >> 8;
 
  var result= new Uint8Array(view.buffer);
  return result
}
```

[*3:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49348743/converting-float32array-to-uint8array-while-preserving-ieee-754-representation) from this one, figure how to save the point coordinates

```
//point To ArrayBuffer - 3x 8 bits
function Pt2ArrBuf(x,y,z){
  var float32 = new Float32Array(3);
  float32[0] = x;
  float32[1] = y;
  float32[2] = z;

  var f = new Float64Array(float32);
  var pt = new Int8Array(f.buffer);  
  
  return pt;
}
```

[*4:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071463/how-can-i-merge-typedarrays-in-javascript/14071518) preparing the data sequence and concatenating the TypedArrays

```
//here I write the file the way i Need it to be...

const binaryData = [
    int2ArrBuf(9),
    strsize(8),
    str2ab('<POINTS>'),
    int2ArrBuf(3),
    Xint2ArrBuf(2),
    strsize(1),
    str2ab('A'),
    Pt2ArrBuf(10.5,10,10),
    Xint2ArrBuf(2),
    strsize(1),
    str2ab('B'),
    Pt2ArrBuf(-20,10,0.7),
    int2ArrBuf(10),
    strsize(9),
    str2ab('</POINTS>') 
  ];

//here I join the many TypedArrays into one...
const mergedInt8Array = new Int8Array(binaryData.map(typedArray => [...new Int8Array(typedArray.buffer)]).flat());
console.log(mergedInt8Array);
```

[*5:](https://codepen.io/david_bulte/pen/pJJGzV) Codepen from David

[*6:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985406/javascript-save-typed-array-as-blob-and-read-back-in-as-binary-data/37017514#37017514) Correction on the blob syntax

```
//*5:direct download via FileSaver.js
var SaveButton = document.getElementById('save');
SaveButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  var filename = document.getElementById("name").value;
  filename += '.txt';
  var blob = new Blob([mergedInt8Array], { type: "application/octet-stream"}); //*6
  saveAs(blob, filename);
});
```

Here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/sergioprof/pen/VwmYyqx) with the Solution. Thank You.